# Place to find Android research papers

Tags: android

I want to find research topics on mobile projects. Are there websites to find Android research papers for free. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.co.id/) or [Citeseer](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/).
Alternatively, you also can search the papers on paid journal service (like IEEE Xplore) and find the paper title with Google or any other search engine. Sometimes, the researcher also give the pdf file of their journal on their personal homepage.